# How extract attributes from input tag and export with a json or xml?

Tags: json, regex, xml

How extract attributes from input tag and export with a json or xml?

My current regex  `/(\S+)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?/g`

INPUT

```
<input name="title" type="text" max="10" min="5">
```

JSON[something like that]

```
{"title":[
    {"max":10, "min": 5, "type": "text"}
]}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1916721

Comment: Aren`t there others ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that with regex i advise using DomDocument for this. 
The code below should help you.

```
<?php

/* your Curl response html */ 
$html = '<input name="title" type="text" max="10" min="5">';

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($html);

$inputsDOMNodeList = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('input');

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($inputsDOMNodeList);
echo '</pre>';

$inputArray = array();
foreach ($inputsDOMNodeList as $inputDOMNodeList) {

    $inputArray[][$inputDOMNodeList->getAttribute('name')] = array(
          'max' => $inputDOMNodeList->getAttribute('max')
        , 'min' => $inputDOMNodeList->getAttribute('min')
        , 'type' => $inputDOMNodeList->getAttribute('type')
    );
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($inputArray);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(json_encode($inputArray));
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: Can I do it with Java too?